# How to add wysiwyg (like CKeditor) to Disqus module textarea?

Tags: wysiwyg, comments

As shown in the following image the input textarea of the Disqus is just plain. Is there a way so we can add wysiwyg (like CKeditor) to it? And that input textbox always located at the top of comments, Is there a way so we can shift it to the bottom of the comments (like core comment module of drupal 7)?

[image: Input Textarea of Disqus]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is impossible. The Disqus comment form is in an iframe originating from disqus.com. It is basically a separate web page embedded within the content of your website.

If your page were to access the Disqus form, it would violate the [Same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). This policy is to keep your information safe. Imagine if another page could read or modify data when you log in to your bank. Bad news.